# microsoft jscript runtime error:function is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi again here is same problem js error function is undefined(onForgotPasswordClick is undefined) , i dont know it is now on simple plain page(without master page), Please help

```
             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js">     </script>

    <link href="Scripts/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#main-page").on('pageinit', function (event) {
                function onForgotPasswordClick() {
                      WebApplication.Services.ForgetPassword.HelloWorld(onMethodSucceeded, onMethodFailed);
                }

                function onMethodSucceeded(results, args) {
                    alert(results);
                }

                function onMethodFailed(error) {
                }
            });

     </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="Form1"  runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">

        <Services>
          <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ForgetPassword.asmx" />
        </Services>
      </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div data-role="page" id="main-page">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="/" class="ui-btn-right">Cancel</a>    <h1>
              Forgot Password</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" >


            <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label" >

                      <legend>   
Username:</legend>
       <input type="text" name="txtUsername" id="txtUsername"   value=""       placeholder="Username" />

                        <legend>
                            Email:</legend>
                        <input type="email" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" value="" placeholder="Email" />

                        <button type="submit"  id="btnLogin" data-theme="b" onclick="onForgotPasswordClick()">
                            Submit</button>
                   <hr />

            </fieldset>
               <div style="display:none" id="msg">

            </div>
        </div>


        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
       <h4>&copy; 2013  All rights reserved.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

here's the similar post...
[microsoft jscript runtime error:test is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115364/microsoft-jscript-runtime-errortest-is-undefined/15118727#15118727)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scope problem:

`onForgotPasswordClick` is defined inside the anonymous function that runs on `$("#main-page").on('pageinit')`, but it is called outside of that function (in the HTML). This isn't possible. However, there is nothing stopping you from calling it within that scope. Add the following line in the script element at the top of the page:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnLogin', onForgotPasswordClick);
```

...Then remove the onclick handler from the button:

```
<button type="submit"  id="btnLogin" data-theme="b">
    Submit</button>
```